# Matlab gamma function: I get Inf for large values

Tags: matlab

I am writing my own code for the pdf of the multivariate t-distribution in Matlab.
There is a piece of code that includes the gamma function.

```
gamma((nu+D)/2) / gamma(nu/2)
```

The problem is that nu=1000, and so I get Inf from the gamma function.
It seems I will have to use some mathematical property of the gamma
function to rewrite it in a different way.

Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the function `gammaln(x)`, which is the equivalent of `log(gamma(x))` but avoids the overflow issue. The function you wrote is equivalent to:

```
exp(gammaln((nu+D)/2) - gammaln(nu/2))
```

Answer (score 0):

The number `gamma(1000/2)` is larger than the maximum number MATLAB support. Thus it shows 'inf'. To see the maximum number in MATLAB, check `realmax`. For your case, if D is not very large, you will have to rewrite your formula. Let us assume that in your case 'D' is an even number. Then the formula you have will be: nu/2 * (nu/2 -1) * ....* (nu/2 - D/2 + 1).

```
sum1 = 1
for i = 1:D/2
sum1 = sum1*(nu/2 - i+1);
end
```

Then `sum1` will be the result you want.

Comment: You mean `sum1 = sum1*(nu/2 + i-1);` which is correct for `D` even (but we don't even know `D` is an integer) , but @Ray has the right way to do it.